# Firefox addon to download a whole site and one step more

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, web-crawler

Do you know any Firefox addon that could download a whole website and download all the sites from the links on the first website? I mean also all images and so on.

Comment: Does it have to be an add-on? Not sure if that would really work. Couple of other questions out there that already deal with downloading web sites. Did you have a look at those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [DownloadThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/).

> DownThemAll is fast, reliable and easy-to-use! It lets you download
>   all the links or images contained in a webpage and much more: you can
>   refine your downloads by fully customizable criteria to get only what
>   you really want! Be in full control over your downloads, dedicated
>   speed and number of parallel connections at any time. Use Metalinks or
>   add mirrors manually to download a file from different servers at the
>   same time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [FoxySpider](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/foxyspider/) addon and configure it by adding:

```
aspx|""|anyotherextensions
```

To "other files" in the "content" option.

Consider the second null extension.

Comment: Extension no longer available...