Retrieve all ZIPs from specific site subdirectory
I'm trying to retrieve the *.ZIP files from this Zophar.net Music section, specifically the NES console. The files are freely downloadable per each game separately, which will be a huge time sink to go through each game's page back and forth. For example, here is a game: https://www.zophar.net/music/nintendo-nes-nsf/river-city-ransom-[street-gangs] and when moused over the link shows up as https://fi.zophar.net/soundfiles/nintendo-nes-nsf/river-city-ransom-[street-gangs]/afqgtyjl/River%20City%20Ransom%20%20%5BStreet%20Gangs%5D%20%28MP3%29.zophar.zip
I have poured over a dozen promising Google results from SuperUser and StackExchange and I cannot seem to find a command line with WGET that doesn't end with 3 paragraphs worth of code and ending the script. I managed once combination of tags using MPEK commands that allowed the whole site tree of htmls and about 44MB in a folder, but ignored the ZIPs I'm after. I don't want to mirror the whole site as I understand it's about 15TB and I don't want to chew up huge bandwidth for the site, nor do I have an interest in everything else hosted. Even if I just grab a page of results here and there.
I also have tried HTTRACK and TinyScraper with no luck, was well as VisualWGET and WinWGET. I don't know how to view the FTP directly in a read-only state to try that way.
Is there a working command line that would just retrieve the NES music ZIP files listed in that directory? I just don't seem to know enough about this. If I need to mirror the directory specifically as the NES console that's fine as long as the ZIPs become local to me as well. The links are open and public.

Welcome to Superuser. Please note that both aspects of your question as it is currently phrased, are off topic: Superuser is not a script writing service, and questions asking that we recommend products are tools are off topic. Please consider rewriting your question focusing more on what you have tried, how you have tried it, and the specific outcomes (simply saying "no luck" does not tell us HOW something failed, and knowing how something failed is often critically important to understanding the problem clearly).

See https://superuser.com/questions/317138/firefox-addon-to-download-a-whole-site-and-one-step-more fro browser extensions, not script
